# Journey doesn't send email when I add filters in contact filter

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, attribute-group

I have a couple of attribute groups with linked data extensions and i would like to use some of these in a contact filter in a journey. however when i even use a simple filter that should work, the journey decides to send no emails. am i missing something?

Comment: Does it trigger email if you don’t add the filter? If yes , it could be other problem than the filter

Comment: yes it triggers the email if i don't add the filter.